# Instance of Chrome Class Python

Tags: class, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, instance

when we create an object of Chrome Class using a code:

```py
#Creating an instance of Chrome class of webdriver module
Chrome_class_object = webdriver.Chrome()

#Printing an Output
print(type(Chrome_class_object))
```

Output:

```
<class 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'>
```

we see in output that the object belongs to `selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver` class but not a Chrome class but we created it through Chrome class of webdriver so it should belong to Chrome Class. Why is that so?

Creating an instance of Chrome Class of webdriver module in selenium library

Answer (score 0):

[WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) is the interface, where as [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) implements the *WebDriver* class. Treat *WebDriver* as a contract with skeleton of the methods but without any body. The ChromeDriver/GeckoDriver can implement those methods as per their standards.

So you can't create an object of an *interface* and have to create it from the child class implementing the *WebDriver* interface. Hence when you:

```
Chrome_class_object = webdriver.Chrome()
print(type(Chrome_class_object))
```

The output is:

```
<class 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `WebDriver` class is a generic class that acts as a base for different browser-specific implementations, such as `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `Edge`, etc. Each browser-specific implementation extends the WebDriver class and provides its own unique functionality and methods.

In the case of `webdriver.Chrome()`, the `Chrome` class is a subclass of `WebDriver` specifically tailored for controlling the Chrome browser. It inherits all the methods and properties of the `WebDriver` class and adds additional functionality specific to Chrome.

So, when you print the type of the `Chrome` object, it shows `selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver`, indicating that the object belongs to the `WebDriver` class for Chrome.

Even though you created the instance using the `Chrome` class, the type of the object reflects the underlying implementation class, which is the `WebDriver` class for `Chrome`.